# What would be the ramifications of forcing magento to always be in "Single Store Mode"?

Tags: magento

What would be the ramification of forcing magento to always be in "Single Store Mode"?

> Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode();

Comment: What would be the best way to change this value?

Comment: The ramification would be that it would always be in single store mode. :) But, honestly I have no idea what side effects this would have. I imagine that it wouldn't be too big of a deal if you really only have one store.

Comment: :)  have lots of websites, each with one store... must I override the core/../../Form.php class just to change this variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One effect would be to hide the Store Scope selection boxes seen throughout admin. Since you have several websites this would mean you cannot choose between them when you might want to.